# changing background color for the headers in NSTableView

Tags: swift, nstableview

Im trying to change the background color of a header row in a view-based NSTableView but not having any luck

tried this:

```
tableView.headerView?.layer?.backgroundColor = CGColor.black
```

and this (as was suggested in an earlier Obj-C post from a while ago):

```
for column in tableView.tableColumns {
    column.headerCell.backgroundColor = NSColor(red: 0/255, green: 108/255, blue: 178/255, alpha: 1)
    column.headerCell.textColor = NSColor.blue
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Creating a custom `NSTableHeaderCell` subclass and setting `NSTableColumn`'s `headerCell` property allows you to customize the appearance of your table's header row.

Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstableheadercell) recommends overriding the `drawInterior:withFrame` method when customizing a header cell, but this will not fill the background color for the whole cell - overriding `draw:withFrame` is needed. Calling `drawInterior` will draw the header's label and other elements. If you want to keep the header's content centered vertically in the cell, adjusting the interior frame is necessary.

```
override func draw(withFrame cellFrame: NSRect, in controlView: NSView) {
    NSColor.gray.setFill()
    NSBezierPath.fill(cellFrame)

    let interiorFrame = CGRect(x: cellFrame.origin.x, y: cellFrame.origin.y + 4.0, width: cellFrame.size.width, height: 14.0)
    drawInterior(withFrame: interiorFrame, in: controlView)
}
```

One thing to note - the column separator lines will need to be drawn as well if you want them.

Answer (score 0):

I also have same problem. I found out that the headercell is inherit from NSTextFieldCell. Which have background Color properties. you can access to that and set it to new color. remember to set draw background to YES.

```
*when you create new column*
[[newCol headerCell] setDrawsBackground:YES];


- (void)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView didClickTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn{
    [[tableColumn headerCell] setBackgroundColor:<color you want to change to>];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a colored subview is probably the cleanest way to achieve this. It goes between the default background and the cells that draw the header text and controls

```
NSRect rect = tableview.headerView.frame;
rect.size.width = 10000; /// just pick something wide enough here
MyColoredView * coverView = [[MyColoredView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
coverView.autoresizingMask = tableview.headerView.autoresizingMask;
[tableview.headerView.superview addSubview:aView positioned:NSWindowBelow relativeTo:tableview.headerView];
```